# Errorbars with factors in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a graph with barplots and want to add errorbars, but really struggle with it.

```
sd_int <-R %>%
  group_by(PSm, Day) %>%
  summarise(sd = sd(int))
mean_int <-R %>%
  group_by(PSm, Day) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(int))
print(sd_int)
print(mean_int)
combined_data <- merge(mean_int, sd_int, by = c("PSm", "Day"))


ggplot(R, aes(x=PSm,y=int/60,fill=PSm))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Day) +
  theme_gray()+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#CD6600", high = "#EEAD0E") +
  ylab("Interaction duration in minutes")+
  scale_x_discrete(NULL)+
  ggtitle("Interactions between males and females by \nmale problem solving ability per day")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=19), axis.text = element_text(size = 10.3)
        , axis.title.y = element_text(size=18), strip.text = element_text(size=13.5))+
  annotate("text", x=-0.2, y=-1, label= "no problemsolver")+
  annotate("text", x=1.2, y=-1, label= "problemsolver")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=int-sd_int, ymax=int+sd_int),  width=0.15,size=0.8)
```

this is what I got so far.

```
print(sd_int)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   PSm [2]
    PSm   Day    sd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1  65.1
2     0     2  25.7
3     0     3  16.4
4     1     1  68.5
5     1     2  27.4
6     1     3  29.0
> print(mean_int)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   PSm [2]
    PSm   Day  mean
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1 90.3 
2     0     2  7.28
3     0     3  6.97
4     1     1 88.7 
5     1     2 15.9 
6     1     3 12.5
```

but if I try to get errorbars ist says:

Warning messages:

1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : '-' is not useful for factors

2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : '+' does not make sense for factors

I also already tried to combine mean and sd, or to transform it into a numeric matrix, but nothing worked.

Comment: sd_int is not a column name. You are trying to subtract an entire dataframe. Please read warning messages more carefully.

Comment: I am new to R, so what do I have to do?

Comment: okay I used mean+-sd now and got errorbars, that are double the size of my bars

Comment: Looking at our data, it is expected that the error bars are large. Compare the `sd` column of `sd_int` with the `mean` column of `mean_int`: on the second row you have a mean of 7.28 and a SD of 25.7.

Comment: Oh shoot, and what does this mean?

Comment: That you have highly variable data, i.e., for the same day and same problem solving ability, you have both long and short interactions.

Comment: Sounds like you might be new to statistics as well. You will need understanding of the theory behind the code to use the power of R effectively.